# Deleting objects from Database many to many

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, many-to-many

I have spring boot application , and one part of it is storing files and their types .
So i have Attachment table for files, Type table for types and attachments_types for storing relation between them.
For example i have file that have id 123456 and type with id 1.
so i have situation like this in my database.

Attachments:

| id | filename | fileType |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | test.docx | docx |

Type

| type_id | type_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | "TYPE_DOCX" |

attachments_types
attachment_id     type_id
123456            1

and when i want to delete attachments from Attachments table it also deletes "TYPE_DOCX" from Type table.
How can i fix this

this is my Attachment entity

```
@Entity
@SuperBuilder
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "attachments")
public class Attachment  {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    private UUID id;

    private String fileName;

    private String fileType;

    @Lob
    private byte[] data;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "attachments_types",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "attachment_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "type_id"))
    private Set<Type> types;
```

Type entity

```
@Entity
@SuperBuilder
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "type")
public class Type {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long typeId;

    @Column(name = "type_name")
    private String typeName;

}
```

Attachment repository

```
    @Transactional
    void deleteByFileName(String fileName);

    @Modifying
    @Transactional
    @Query(value = "DELETE FROM attachments_types WHERE attachment_id = :attachment_id ", nativeQuery = true)
    void deleteFromAttachmentsTypes(@Param("attachment_id") UUID attachment_id);
```

and Attachment service

```
 @Override
    public void deleteFile(String fileName) {
        var attachment = attachmentRepository.findByFileName(fileName).get();
        
        attachmentRepository.deleteFromAttachmentsTypes(attachment.getId());

        attachmentRepository.deleteByFileName(fileName);
    }
```

I know that this can be maybe fix by changing CascadeType in @ManyToMany  properties but i dont know how

Comment: are you setting the delete cascade property on these keys in the table when it was defined? I don't think delete cascade is the default in postgresql

Comment: No i mean setting CascadeType properties in @ManyToMany

Comment: `@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, ...)` would be the culprit or at least part of the problem. If you delete an `Attachment` JPA would cascade the delete down to `types`. Since I assume `Types` is independent from `Attachments` (i.e. those entries can exist even if there is no attachment at all) I'd remove this cascading. You probably never need to create, delete or update types at the same time as attachments (create might be somewhat different though).

Comment: So just removing properties from @ManyToMany will fix this?

Comment: There may be more to this in the code you didn't share but removing the `cascade` or replacing it with an array of only the relevant values should help. You might want to read up on what cascading means in JPA to gain a better understanding on when to use it.